# how to get all children by multiple parent ids using IN() clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all children records by their parent IDs(multiple) using IN clause but its return only children belong to first parent id passed in IN Clause

here is my query to MySQL db

```
SELECT column1 AS c1, column2 as c2 from table where parent_id IN(1,2,3)
```

the above query returns the children belongs to parent id 1, but I want to get all children belongs to parent ids 1,2 and 3. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query per se, without seeing table structures and sample data and the code you are using it's hard to say what might be the problem.

Comment: IN query written above is correct. Maybe there is no data with parent_id = 2 or 3

Comment: thnx dear, @Nick, iahave using codeigniter active records method and my code is  $result = $this->glxspace->select('nlg_id AS NI, nlg_link AS NL, nlg_title AS NT, nlg_shortDetails AS NSD')->from('notifications_links_glxspace')->where_in('nlg_menus_id',$menus_notification_parent_ids)->get(); this code generate the above mentiond mysql query... whole code is lengthy

Comment: dear @Ananth all parents Ids have childs in table

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are expecting the Child which has all the `Parent_id`s 1, 2 and 3.

The following query will help:

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName
WHERE Parent_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY ColumnName
HAVING COUNT(Parent_id) = 3
```

Comment: Although assuming each node-parent combination is unique, you don't have to add the `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` function, do you?

Comment: thanks @Arulkumar, i have tried this but not working, its returning null (0 records)

Comment: @justmasif Can you please create a [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with correct MySQL version, it should include table schema, sample data and expected output. So it will helpful to solve the issue.